# How to return more than one match with regex expression

Tags: regex, string, multiple-matches, fme

Hi I am currently trying to use regex (in FME, using StringSearcher) to match and return every instance where there is a hashtag, and the 5 characters following it.

e.g
"#29777 is close to #19666 and also make sure #12345 is there"

would return:
"#29777 #19666 #12345"

I currently have this as my Regex expression which works, but i'm not sure how to get more than one return:

```
(?<=#).{5}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with your regex? It seems to return the digits you need.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Why are you using a lookbehind if you want to select `#`?

Comment: See [StringSearcher Docs](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/stringsearcher.htm), specifically the section describing *All Matches List Name*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match hashtags with only 5 chars you can try this pattern:

```
#.{5}[\s]|#.{5}$
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working using regex from Carl Kristensen and a suggestion by booboo. The code still only returned the first match, but by populating all matches field and using a list exploder in FME, I was able to get all matches.

Thanks again for all of your help :)